# SQL Server 2K: The calculation of index size

Tags: sql-server

Based on the info using **sp_spaceused**

```
rows           reserved    data         index_size  unused

7703020     497944 KB   497968 KB     16 KB       -40 KB
```

I create an noncluster index with a column of **numeric(18, 0)** that is 9 bytes in size; then the index_size turns into **153064 KB**.

How is the # calculated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like you don't have ANY indexes on that table, at all, for the index size to only be 16kb.

After creating your index, each row is consuming a tad over 20 bytes in index space. For 7.7 million rows that seems fairly normal.

For detailed information on how to estimate the index size, [see this article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190620.aspx).

Man, I would hate to be running any queries over almost 8 million rows with no indexes...

Comment: Hi, thanks. I just simplify the question for ease of discussion.